# mvc 3 checkbox @value failing in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, razor

I have the following line of code in a partial view

```
@Html.CheckBox("selectedUnit", new { @value =  item.data.Id })
```

This partial view is a table that allows for selecting of table rows.  In my postback i then get a list of my checkboxes in the form with either the Id or "false".

My issue is in my original call to the partial view everything works as intended, but when i call it from the second page (conformation page with selectable rows for removing before saving) I get a server exception saying:

```
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Source Error:

Line 73:     <tr>
Line 74:         <td class="checkboxColumn">
Line 75:             @Html.CheckBox("selectedUnit", new { @value =  item.data.Id })
Line 76:         </td>   
Line 77:         <td>
```

I've got no idea why it works when called the first time, but not the second time.  Its the exact same partial view with the exact same set of data.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does your action look like for the second page?

Comment: Past breakpoint to this helper, and look what is the value of item.data.Id

Comment: Ive been messing around with it and it even a basic checkbox call is failing in this partial view when called from the second page.
the following line is failing as well:

`@Html.CheckBox("selectedUnit")`

The only difference is that the working one is returning PartialView that calls 2 other partial views (where it is working) and one is returning View that calls the partial view (where it is failing)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `item.data.id` is returning Boolean value type. Try also following one :

```
@Html.CheckBox("chxPoo", item.data.id)
```

Comment: @value doesn't have to be of type boolean.  It can be of type string and will be returned.  This is how it is set up now and is working just fine when called from my main page via an ajax call returning a partial view.  It is only failing when called via a regular postback and returning a view that holds the partial view.